# swift/ios8: mimick action Sheet behaviour

Tags: swift, uiview, ios8

As it is highly discouraged to use the Action Sheet for overlay controls I am currently trying to mimick it with my own subview but somehow the containing components wont be displayed?

code:

```
@IBAction func showActionSheet(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("SHOW STUFF")
        let newView:UIView = UIView()
        let myColor:UIColor = UIColor(red:255.0, green:255.0, blue:255.0, alpha:0.6)

        newView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        newView.backgroundColor = myColor
        view.addSubview(newView)


        var pickerFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height-(self.view.frame.height+self.view.frame.height-200), self.view.frame.width-20, self.view.frame.height/2)
        var picker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: pickerFrame);
        picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        view.addSubview(picker)

        var okButton = UIButton()
        okButton.titleLabel?.text = "Ok"
        okButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        okButton.frame = CGRectMake(0 , self.view.frame.width-160, self.view.frame.width, 80)

        var cancelButton = UIButton()
        cancelButton.titleLabel?.text = "Abbrechen"
        cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0 , self.view.frame.width-80, self.view.frame.width, 800)

        view.addSubview(okButton)
        view.addSubview(cancelButton)

        let secondView:UIView = UIView()

        secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        view.addSubview(secondView)


    }
```

the secondView was just for testing purposes - it will get drawn normally, but somehow my controls wont be

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the controls to `newView` the view you placed over the old view. Also the buttons are too big and white. Try this code. This will make them visible. Adjust their height to match the frame of the view and then set the color back. I just changed the background colors to get an idea of the frame. Also call `UIButton.setTitle(:forState:)` to set the title of the buttons.

```
@IBAction func showActionSheet(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("SHOW STUFF")
    let newView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
    let myColor:UIColor = UIColor(red:255.0, green:255.0, blue:0, alpha:0.6)

    newView.backgroundColor = myColor
    view.addSubview(newView)


    var pickerFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width-20, 200)
    var picker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: pickerFrame);
    picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    newView.addSubview(picker)

    var okButton = UIButton()
    okButton.setTitle("Ok", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    okButton.setTitle("Ok", forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    okButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    okButton.frame = CGRectMake(0 , self.view.frame.width-160, self.view.frame.width, 80)

    var cancelButton = UIButton()
    cancelButton.setTitle("Abbrechen", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cancelButton.setTitle("Abbrechen", forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0 , self.view.frame.width-80, self.view.frame.width, 200)

    newView.addSubview(okButton)
    newView.addSubview(cancelButton)

}
```